# how to get dynamic created text box value from panel in c# on button click

Tags: c#, dynamic, panel

I Create dynamic text box on button click inside panel and store number 
and want to retrieve its text and make total of that number how can i do that?

Following is my code for text box generation

```
        private void btnMaterialAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {
            TextBox[] txtTeamNames = new TextBox[100];
            txtTeamNames[i] = new TextBox();
            string name = "TeamNumber" + i.ToString();
            txtTeamNames[i].Location = new Point(1,  i * 30  );
            txtTeamNames[i].Width = 30;
            txtTeamNames[i].Name = "ID" + i;
            txtTeamNames[i].Visible = true;
            int num = i + 1 ;
            txtTeamNames[i].Text = num.ToString();
            panel1.Controls.Add(txtTeamNames[i]);

        }
```

How to count total value of each text box and display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the Array and use a List at **Class Level** (not a local variable in your method):

```
    private List<TextBox> TextBoxes = new List<TextBox>();

    private void btnMaterialAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox tb = new TextBox();
        int i = TextBoxes.Count + 1;
        tb.Location = new Point(1, i * 30);
        tb.Width = 30;
        tb.Name = "ID" + i;
        tb.Text = i.ToString();
        TextBoxes.Add(tb);
        panel1.Controls.Add(tb);
    }
```

Now you can iterate over that List when to get a total:

```
    private void btnTotal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int value;
        int total = 0;
        foreach (TextBox tb in TextBoxes)
        {
            if (int.TryParse(tb.Text, out value))
            {
                total = total + value;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show(tb.Name + " = " + tb.Text, "Invalid Value");
            }
        }
        MessageBox.Show("total = " + total.ToString());
    }
```